# How do I reset a countdown timer when it reaches 0? (Xcode 4)

Tags: xcode4, timer, nstimer, countdown

first question and I have researched the heck out of this and can't seem to find any answers.

I would like to implement a countdown timer in my app that starts at 30 seconds and resets when it hits 0. It will count back by 1 second intervals. I have played around with the resources that Apple provides and I can't seem to implement the NStimer to do as I just explained. Are there any suggestions on how I could code this? I would eventually like to link this to a button that will start the timer when it is pressed. I appreciate any advice on this topic!

Answer (score 1):

**in your .h**

```
@interface YourObject : NSObject {
   int countdownNumber;
   NSTimer* timer;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int countdownNumber;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer* timer;

- (IBAction)clickOnButton:(id)sender
- (void)countdown;
@end
```

**in your .m**

```
yourInitMethod {  // ViewDidLoad, initWith...., or any init method you have
  self.timer = nil;
}

- (IBAction)clickOnButton:(id)sender {
    if (self.timer != nil) {
         [self.timer invalidate];
    }

   self.countdownNumber = 30;
   self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)countdown {
   self.countdownNumber--;
   if (self.countdownNumber == 0) {
      [self.timer invalidate];
      self.timer = nil;
   }
}
```